Questions about the exchange of lim sup and sup lim in stochastic control.
I wonder if the following lemma is true?
Suppose $f(\gamma,u)$ is a real function on $[0,1]\times[\underline{c},\bar{c}]$, which is constant not important. $f$ is Lipchitz continuous in u.$g(\gamma)$ is another real function which is continuous at the point $\gamma=0$. Then it holds that
$\lim_{\gamma\downarrow 0}\sup_{u\in\mathcal{A}[g(\gamma),\bar{c}]}f(\gamma,u)=\lim_{\gamma\downarrow0}\sup_{u\in\mathcal{A}[g(0),\bar{c}]} f(\gamma,u)\leq \sup_{u\in\mathcal{A}[g(0),\bar{c}]}\lim_{\gamma\downarrow0} f(\gamma,u)$, where $\mathcal{A}[a,b]$ represent the set of controls which are non-decreasing as time goes by and values in [a,b].
And I write a simple proof, I think maybe its wrong, please tell me the mistake.
Proof:
We assume that $g(\gamma)$ monotone increases by $\gamma$. For any $u\in\mathcal{A}[g(\gamma),\bar{c}]$, it must hold that $u\in\mathcal{A}[g(0),\bar{c}]$. So we conclude that
\begin{align}\label{lemmaestimate1}
\lim_{\gamma\downarrow 0}\sup_{u\in\mathcal{A}[g(\gamma),\bar{c}]}f(\gamma,u)\leq\lim_{\gamma\downarrow0}\sup_{u\in\mathcal{A}[g(0),\bar{c}]}f(\gamma,u).     
\end{align}
On the other hand, let $A(\gamma)\equiv\sup_{u\in\mathcal{A}[g(0),\bar{c}]}f(\gamma,u)$ , $A=\lim_{\gamma\to0}A(\gamma)$. For any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $u^*\in\mathcal{A}[g(0),\bar{c}]$, such that $f(\gamma,u^*)\geq A(\gamma)-\epsilon$. Then let $u(\gamma)=u^*\vee g(\gamma)\in\mathcal{A}[g(\gamma),\bar{c}]$. By the lipchitz continuous of $f$, we get
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\gamma\downarrow0}|f(\gamma,u(\gamma))-f(\gamma,u^*)|\leq \lim_{\gamma\downarrow0} K|u(\gamma)-u^*|\leq \lim_{\gamma\downarrow0}|g(\gamma)-g(0)|\leq 0.
\end{align*}
So we conclude that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\gamma\downarrow 0}f(\gamma,u(\gamma))= \lim_{\gamma\downarrow 0}f(\gamma,u^*))\geq \lim_{\gamma\to0}A(\gamma)-\epsilon=A-\epsilon.
\end{align*}
Since $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary chosen, it follows that
\begin{align}\label{lemmaestimate2}
\lim_{\gamma\downarrow 0}\sup_{u\in\mathcal{A}g(\gamma),\bar{c}]}f(\gamma,u)\geq A
=\lim_{\gamma\downarrow0}\sup_{u\in\mathcal{A}[g(0),\bar{c}]}f(\gamma,u).      
\end{align}
Combine equations above, it holds that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{\gamma\downarrow 0}\sup_{u\in\mathcal{A}[g(\gamma),\bar{c}]}f(\gamma,u)=\lim_{\gamma\downarrow0}\sup_{u\in\mathcal{A}[g(0),\bar{c}]} f(\gamma,u).
\end{align*}
Moreover, for any $v\in\mathcal{A}[g(0),\bar{c}]$ such that
\begin{align*}
f(\gamma,v)\geq A(\gamma)-\epsilon,    
\end{align*}
we have
\begin{align*}
\sup_{u\in\mathcal{A}[g(0),\bar{c}]}\lim f(\gamma,u)\geq \lim_{\gamma\to0}f(\gamma,v)\geq A-\epsilon.
\end{align*}
Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary chosen. We prove it.
